# cant setBackgroundDrawable in actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, drawable

I have a function updateActionBar to change the action's bar background. When the app starts, this function change the background :

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header_bacjground_test));
```

THe scenario is : the app moves to new activity and that activity finishes by calling finish() function( the app returns to the main acivity), setBackgroundDrawable doesnt work even it is called. The background is set to black while the expected background is gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity file, override onStart() method and write

```
 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header_background_test));
```

Whenever you move activity to front or back, the header will remain same backgorund

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I know, when the activity is brought to front, onStart will be called. In this case, setBackgroundDrawable will be executed. However, it is not. I wonder is that because the resource is not ready at that time???